# How to fetch songs from ipodlibrary and play using AVPlayer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

i want to select songs from ipod Library and play it using avplayer i want the music to continue playing even after the app goes to background i am new to iOS programming can anyone help me out ..

Thanks

Comment: And I want an all-expensive-paid month-long holiday to Hawaii :)

Comment: The wronger the question is asked - the wronger the answer is got

Comment: i have worked on mpmusicplayercontroller class ... but it doesnt support background play . i heard avplayer supports background play

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To allow the user to pick a song (or songs) from their music library, use the `MPMediaPickerController` class.

```
-(void) pickSong {

    // Create picker view
    MPMediaPickerController* picker = [[MPMediaPickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;

    // Check how to display
    if ([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {

        // Show in popover
        [popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
        popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:picker];
        [popover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];

    } else {

        // Present modally
        [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];

    }

}
```

Change `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem` if you're not showing it from a button on the right side of title bar.

Then you need to listen for the result by implementing the delegate:

**Called when the user cancelled the selection:**

```
-(void) mediaPickerDidCancel:(MPMediaPickerController *)mediaPicker {

    // Dismiss selection view
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    [popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    popover = nil;

}
```

**Called when the user chose something:**

```
-(void) mediaPicker:(MPMediaPickerController *)mediaPicker didPickMediaItems:(MPMediaItemCollection *)mediaItemCollection {

    // Dismiss selection view
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    [popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    popover = nil;

    // Get AVAsset
    NSURL* assetUrl = [mediaItemCollection.representativeItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];
    AVURLAsset* asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:assetUrl options:nil];

    // Create player item
    AVPlayerItem* playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];

    // Play it
    AVPlayer* myPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
    [myPlayer play]; 

}
```

You'll need a `UIPopoverController* popover;` in your class .h file. Also you should retain `myPlayer` somewhere...

To allow music to continue in the background, add an `audio` string to the array in your Info.plist under the `UIBackgroundModes` key.