# How to access phone memory from application - iOS

Tags: ios, avplayer

I have an music application that plays songs from urls using `AVPlayer`. According to new requirement user should be able to listen their local songs (contines in phone memory) also through this music app. I want to know few things about this.

1) How to access local memory within my application.

2) Can I use already exists `AVPlayer` to play local songs too.

Any tutorial or examples uch appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) It depends on what you mean by 'local memory'. You app's local folder, or the device's iPodLibrary?

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSHomeDirectory()
                          stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
NSLog(@"Content of local documents directory: %@", 
          [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:nil]);
```

This will print out all the files that's currently in your app's document-folder. You can store files here too. This is only for your app, not shared by any other app on your device. I do not think you're able to find the `.m4a`-audio files from your iPod from your application, I'm guessing Apple has hidden them so developers can't mess with them, or start pirating etc.

2) As it turns out, it looks like you can! Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11540212/how-to-fetch-songs-from-ipodlibrary-and-play-using-avplayer/11541101#11541101).

Comment: Thanks for ur answer.. for q1 cant we get local songs like we get photos from imagepicker? is there any way to get songs like that way?

Comment: Both of you, the OP and you seem to mix up the terms "local memory" with "local filesystem'.

Comment: @Till I was thinking he didn't actually mean "local memory" when he asked the question, so I decided to answer with the same terminology so he could understand it easier. A silly decision, I might add, I see that now. I'm no superman when it comes to these terms anyway though, I'm usually wondering whether people are talking about RAM or disk when they refer to Memory, but that might be my native language's stupid naming of such things kicking in.

Comment: @iDia You should read the answer I provided in q2, it uses `MPMediaPickerController`, a simple google-image search can show that it looks like what you're requesting, here: https://www.google.com/search?q=MPMediaPickerController&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=no&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&ei=oYQVUolv8dvhBJfXgIAC&biw=1920&bih=1115&sei=pYQVUpT1GeOC4gTpmoHADQ